# Conditional expressions in Python's documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I understand correctly, in Python3, a conditional expression is something of the form "x if C else y". For instance, if I understand correctly, the following block is a conditional expression which return the string 'a'

```
'a' if 0<1 else 'b'
```

while the following block is a conditional expression that returns 'b'

```
'a' if 0>1 else 'b'
```

In the Python language reference the [grammar rule for conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is given by those lines:

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
```

I  don't understand this rule because for instance it would say with my above example that `'a'` and `0>1` were derived from `or_test` and that `'b'` was derived from `expression`, whereas for me `'a'` and `'b'` should both be derived by the same rule (`expr` here). The only thing that make sense to me would be replace the first grammar rule by

```
conditional_expression ::=  expression \["if" or_test "else" expression\]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This would result in the problem that if you write `'a' if 0 > 1 else 'b' if 1 > 2 else 'c'` would be ambiguous to parse.

Comment: It might be worth looking at the PEP that introduced it: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I see the point, and it clarifies my doubts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: because it would introduce ambiguity.

> I don't understand this rule because for instance it would say with my above example that `'a'` and `0>1` were derived from `or_test` and that `'b'` was derived from expression, whereas for me `'a'` and `'b'` should both be derived by the same rule (`expr` here).

Well both `or_test` and `expr` can result in a string literal. Indeed if we move down the grammar we will see that:

```
or_test  ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test
and_test ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test
not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
or_expr  ::=  xor_expr | or_expr "|" xor_expr
xor_expr ::=  and_expr | xor_expr "^" and_expr
and_expr ::=  shift_expr | and_expr "&" shift_expr
shift_expr ::=  a_expr | shift_expr ( ">" ) a_expr
a_expr ::=  m_expr | a_expr "+" m_expr | a_expr "-" m_expr
m_expr ::=  u_expr | m_expr "*" u_expr | m_expr "//" u_expr | m_expr "/" u_expr
            | m_expr "%" u_expr
u_expr ::=  power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr
power ::=  primary ["**" u_expr]
primary ::=  atom | attributeref | subscription | slicing | call
atom      ::=  identifier | literal | enclosure
literal ::=  stringliteral | bytesliteral
             | integer | floatnumber | imagnumber
```

So eventually an `or_test` can lead to a string literal. You can see an `or_test` as an expression, but where certain things are not possible anymore (except when we use brackets).

The two important things we can not do with an `or_test` is construct an `if`-`then`-`else` again; and construct a lambda expression. Yes we can make the first item a lambda expression, and a new `if`-`then`-`else`, but not without using brackets.

Why us this necessary? Well a grammer should be unambigous. It means that if we construct the syntax tree from a certain expression, there should only be *one* such tree.

If we would allow to use an `expression` as first item as well, we could write an expression like:

```
'a' if a else 'b' if c else 'c'
```

Now we *can* write that in Python, since Python can derive that `'a'` belongs to the `or_test`, `a` to the second `or_test`, and `'b' if c else 'c'` to the `expression`. In case the former was an expression, we could also match `'a' if a else 'b'` as an expression (which is wrong according to *Python* standards).

The same holds for using a lambda expression. If we write:

```
lambda a, b: 'a' if a else 'b' if c else 'c'
```

then Python will parse this as:

```
lambda a, b: ('a' if a else 'b' if c else 'c')
```

But if we would enable lambda expressions in the first `or_test`, then Python could have also parsed it as:

```
(lambda a, b: 'a') if a else 'b' if c else 'c'
```

This would not have been *per se* wrong, but the designers of Python picked the former interpretation over the latter. It is important that there can be only *one* interpretation, since otherwise two people could run the same Python program with a different interpreter, and obtain different results.

Comment: Nice explanation, and thanks for showing which grammar rules are applied to or_test to reach stringliteral.